# Changing the hostname in a chroot environment also changes the hostname outside

Tags: chroot

I chrooted into my testsystem with

```
mount /dev/vg0/vm01.buster-test-disk /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/
mount -t proc none /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/proc
mount --bind /dev /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/dev
mount -t sysfs sysfs /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/sys
chroot /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/ /bin/bash
```

## adapted the Hostname and exit

```
hostname buster-test
echo buster-test > /etc/hostname
echo "127.0.0.1 buster-test" >> /etc/hosts
exit
```

### unmount

```
umount /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/proc
umount /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/dev
umount /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/sys
umount -l /media/vm01.buster-test-disk
```

## Problem

now the host has its hostname set to `buster-test` even if I login in in another shell

Why did the hostname change? And are there other things that could change outside the chroot, when doing stuff inside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Running `hostname buster-test` changed the hostname in the running kernel (on Linux, in the current [UTS namespace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/uts_namespaces.7.html)). `chroot` on its own doesn’t control that at all, so the hostname change was visible outside too.

When you use `chroot`, you’re only limiting access to a portion of the file system; anything which isn’t managed in a file system won’t be constrained to the “environment” created by `chroot`. This includes network setup, the date and time, user permissions, etc. To constrain such changes, you need to use [namespaces](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/namespaces.7.html) (or similar technologies on non-Linux systems); on Linux, you can isolate processes by running them with [`unshare`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/unshare.1.html).

Comment: so I guess `echo buster-test > /etc/hostname` would have been enough

Comment: Probably not, you need something to act upon that.

Comment: I thought the setting in /etc/hostname would be used after a reboot?

Comment: Oh, right, you don’t need it to be used *now*, you’re trying to store it in the target disk so that it will be used in your test system, is that correct? Then yes, it will be read during boot in the test system, so writing `/etc/hostname` in the chroot would be sufficient. In fact you don’t even need a chroot here, you can write the two files in `etc` in your mounted file system.

Comment: `unshare --uts chroot /media/vm01.buster-test-disk/` Blocks changes to `hostname` and `domainname` from affecting the rest of the system.

Answer (score 1):

The hostname is the `nodename` part of the `uname(2)`system call and the related data resides inside the kernel.

Unless you have a kernel that is able to handle something like zones with own kernel data structures, a simple `chroot` does not help.

Answer (score 1):

`systemd-nspawn` can be used instead of `chroot` to get a containerized chroot. Containers have better isolation between host and guest systems than `chroot` does.

> `systemd-nspawn` may be used to run a command or OS in a light-weight namespace container. In many ways it is similar to `chroot(1)`, but more powerful since it fully virtualizes the file system hierarchy, as well as the process tree, the various IPC subsystems and the host and domain name.